# KnockoutJS table with input text as row to update value of another cell of the same row

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to knockoutjs and I just want to know if it's possible to have an input text in a table row that when updated will change the value of the cell of that same row.

model:

```
public class RateData{
    private double Rate{ get; set; }
    private double RateUnit{ get; set; }
    private double TotalRate{ get{ return Rate*Unit; }
}

List<RateData> rates = new List<RateData>{
    new RateData{ Rate = 5.0, RateUnit = 1 },
    new RateData{ Rate = 5.0, RateUnit = 2 }
};
```

and in my view:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Rates">
     <tr>
       <td data-bind="text: $data.Rate"></td>
       <td data-bind="value: $data.TotalRate"></td>
       <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.RateUnit class="form-control" /></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to make rate unit to be updatable and everytime I make changes to it, it will also update rate total. Ex.

```
   For Row #1

   RateUnit = 1
   Rate = 5.0

   TotalRate = RateUnit * Rate (5.0)


   For Row #2

   RateUnit = 2
   Rate = 5.0

   TotalRate = RateUnit * Rate (10.0)
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: 1. You cannot use `value` for `td` elements.

Comment: 2. No need for `$data` prefix. `text: Rate` will do.

Comment: 3. In your Javascript view-model, change `TotalRate` to `function() { return this.RateUnit() * this.Rate(); }`.

Comment: 4. Make sure you're using observables as the properties of your view-model.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the data-bind. Please do.
I am using div and Ul, you can replace with table.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Rates">
    <ul>
        <li data-bind="text: $data.Rate"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: $data.Rate * $data.RateUnit()"></li>
        <li><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.RateUnit" class=" form-control" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In your JS. 'data' being your model.

```
self = this;
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self)
self.Rates = ko.observableArray([
        { Rate: 5.0, RateUnit: ko.observable(0) ,TotalRate:0},
        { Rate: 6.0, RateUnit: ko.observable(0) ,TotalRate:0}
    ]);
```